# Conversion of Milliseconds into date is not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an Input XML in which I have an time-stamp in long digit. I am trying to convert it into readable date format. I searched on internet and found few solutions. But none of them is working. Please guide me , what am I missing?.

I want to convert this long time-stamp (milliseconds to 
readable date format).

**Input XML:**

```
<Order>
<value>1467702989532</value>
</Order>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  version="2.0">
<xsl:output method ="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/Order">

      <NewOrder>
          <dateValue>
            <xsl:value-of select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + value * xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S")'/>
           </dateValue>
      </NewOrder>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NewOrder xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <dateValue />
</NewOrder>
```

Comment: Works for me under Oxygen/XML 14 (Saxon-EE 9.4.0.6).  I get `<dateValue>2016-07-05T07:16:29.532</dateValue>`

Comment: What processor are you actually using to perform the transformation? Even though your stylesheet is marked version 2.0, you will need an XSLT 2.0 compliant processor to handle the transformation.

Comment: XSLT 1.0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993455/3016153