# Error in XSL Transformation ABAP

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple xml which is generated from JSON string in ABAP. Now I have to convert the time stamp field "1467990652501" to date format.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
    <object>
    <str name="t">TX</str>
    <num name="i">1467990652501</num>
    </object>
```

I got a way of doing it via xs:dateTime and xs:dayTimeDuration methods. But these methods are avaialble in the namespace "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema". When I Include this in XSL transformation in ABAP(transaction xslt_tool) and run the transformation I am getting an error. I have added the namespace in my XSLTas follows

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
```

Is there something I am missing here.

Thanks

Comment: Does ABAP support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Please post your attempted code and the exact error message.

Comment: Hello Martin, 
    ABAP does support XSLT2.0 but its a tedious process of importing external transformers. So I want to achieve it with 1.0. 
My simple requirement is to convert the timestamp to valid date.

Comment: Hello Michael,
   This is what I use
  <xsl:variable name="vStamp" select="num[@name = 'i']"/>
                   
      <xsl:variable name="vDateStr"
                            select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + $vStamp * xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S")'/>

Comment: You cannot use that code with an XSLT 1.0 processor; XSLT 1.0 has no concept of dates and times.  -- For a solution in in XSLT 1.0, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990478/convert-epoch-to-date-via-xsl-from-xml-attribute-and-display-in-html/27993455#27993455