# convert milliseconds to date in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt

I am trying to convert date which is in milliseconds , e.g. the input xml has 1088499889000 that corresponds to the date 2004-06-29 09:04:49.000GMT.

To try and do this within XSLT they do not seem to have functions for this. Are there any extensions available that I could use for this conversion using xslt 1.0.

Thanks

Comment: If you type "convert milliseconds to date in xslt 1.0" into the search bar into StackOverflow, the third result that comes out is this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990478/convert-epoch-to-date-via-xsl-from-xml-attribute-and-display-in-html/27993455#27993455. I think that does what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert epoch to Date via XSL from XML attribute and display in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990478/convert-epoch-to-date-via-xsl-from-xml-attribute-and-display-in-html)